# Clean way to initialize plugin in newly-added site when plugin has been network activated?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, activation

I've been working on migrating one of my plugins to support multisite installs and am attempting to figure out the cleanest way to handle the following series of events:

1. Plugin is Network Activated
2. New site is added

I'm currently listening to the activation hook which works for every other case, both individual activations and site-wide ones, but I'm not getting an activation hit when the new site is added. [Incidentally, this strikes me as a bug in WP core...](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28363) In any event, I need to catch this series of events and run activation things.

I was looking at combining the [wpmu_create_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog) hook and [is_plugin_active_for_network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active_for_network), but I'm not sure if there might *fingers crossed* be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through Make WordPress, it looks like this is a known [issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14170) that won't be fixed due to scalability concerns with large networks.

That same issue linked above recommends doing exactly the solution discussed above. Specifically, that would look something like this:

```
public static function 145561_activate_new_blog($blog_id) {
   if (is_plugin_active_for_network(plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      // do activation for $blog_id
   }
}
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', '145561_activate_new_blog');
```